# Set all variations out of stock if one variation is out of stock in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, variable-product

We run a self-storage system with WooCommerce and we use WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. Our storage units is a unique product with a Variable Subscription. Each variation has a different billing period (1 month, 3 months, 6 months and 12 months). I need the whole parent product, or at least all variations, to be out of stock if one variation is out of stock.

I didn't find any related setting and I didn't find how to make that possible yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will make all variations out of stock (for specific variable product(s)), when one variation is out of stock ***(also works with WooCommerce subscriptions)***:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'set_all_variations_out_of_stock', 10, 3 );
function set_all_variations_out_of_stock( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    // Set the Id(s) of the related variable product(s) below in the array
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), array(738) ) ){
        $out_of_stock = false; // initializing
        
        // Loop through children variations of the parent variable product
        foreach( $product->get_visible_children() as $_variation_id ) {
            if( $_variation_id != $data['variation_id'] ) {
                $_variation = wc_get_product($_variation_id);
                
                
                if( ! $_variation->is_in_stock() ) {
                    $out_of_stock = true; // Flag as out of stock
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( $out_of_stock ) {
            $data['availability_html'] = '<p class="stock out-of-stock">'. __('Out of stock', 'woocommerce') .'</p>';
            $data['is_in_stock'] = false;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

> **Important note:**
>
> #### Stock can be managed on the parent variable product.
>
> 1. Enable stock management on the variable product (on Inventory tab) and set the stock there.
> 2. Disable stock management on each variation for this variable product.
>
> You are done. The stock management is now handled on the variable
> product.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test it. Something that came to my mind right now, will it also make product in stock if the Variant becomes instock?

Comment: I have upvoted it. But it didn't actually work. I tested it. Please check my screenshots here: https://imgur.com/a/HBuLCxG

Comment: Alright the code worked after I changed the product id. I missed that comment. Is it possible to include all products instead of specifying ID? Because all my products are and will be variable subscriptions.

Comment: Also. It only worked in the front-end. I need it to show "out of stock" in back-end aswell. Is it possible?

Comment: @RJay To make it work for all products, just remove `if( in_array( $product->get_id(), array(738) ) ){` and the closing bracket `}` before  `return $data; `…

Comment: Alright I understand. I got an idea though... Could it be possible to write SQL to change the value of "stock_status" depending on variations in the table called "_wc_product_meta_lookup" ?

Comment: @RJay Just tested now something, **and it works**… **You don't need any code with the following:** First enable stock management on the variable product and set the stock to 1. Then on each variation, disable the stock management… So now you don't need any code and you can remove my answer code. **It's just about settings.** Now when a variation is purchased, all variations goes out of stock. To re enable the product, you just need to restock the variable product (but not the variations). So this works on front end and backend.

Comment: Alright thanks. I have set it like you mentioned. And it should be alright from now on then. I will update here for next sale, but I expect it will go as you said.

Comment: @RJay It will, I have tested that myself.

Comment: Can we set the product out of stock when all it's variations are out of stock ? Stock management is done at variations level and not on a product level. So even when all variations are out of stock the product still displays in Stock.